# Need to code AWS lambda function with S3 triggers

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to code the entire Lambda function creation which can be used to deploy the solution to various environments using github.

Currently my lambda function (.py) is in a script. But the S3 trigger is currently added only through AWS console.

How do i add the event trigger either on S3 bucket or in Lambda function through scripting? I am not allowed to use AWS console, but still want to use the lambda triggers.

THere has to be a way but i can't find a working solution. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You should check [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation)

Answer (score 0):

Serverless Framework is what I use, it's simple to build complex services with aws resources and events. Have a look at https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3/

This is all you need:

```
functions:
  users:
    handler: mypythonfilename.handler
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: mybucketname
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
```

It basically builds the CloudFormation for you, and deploys the lambda with the `serverless deploy` command.